# Inserting Data into SQL database table from multiple aspx web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am currently have an asp.net web site through visual studio that contains three .aspx pages. Each .aspx page has simple label and text box fields in it. There is a button in each web aspx page also that redirects to the second and third page as well as a submit button at the end of the third page. Also behind the buttons there is an sql command/ query that Inserts the input from the textboxes into an sql database. I have one table in the database that I want input from all three pages. When I tried to do this the input from the first page correctly stayed in the first row. Then the input from the second page made its own second row and so on... I am also using a INSERT statement for each web aspx page. I have a picture below of what the database looks like... how can I get all the input into one row

Comment: Seems like you should use a wizard control, not 3 pages.

Comment: Single Page Application is what you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: @Marcel Could you further explain a wizard control for me!? thank you

Comment: @Bibby: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx for example and google around. There are plenty of resources around.

Answer (score 0):

With your current configuration you'll need an update statement instead of an insert statement on the subsequent pages.

You could also do something like session variables and just insert after you've collected all the information.

Comment: I see your comment on the other answer.  You would do something like UPDATE tblmyname SET Nextvalue=variable  WHERE name = name.  But there are so many things wrong with what you're doing.  A name isn't a good unique field.  You shouldn't pass a string like that it opens you up to sql injection attacks.  For starters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it into one row, you need to do one `INSERT` statement and the rest should be `UPDATE` statements.
Each and every `INSERT` statement will create a new row in the database.

When trying to `UPDATE` a row, make sure you add something like `WHERE ID = x`, so you only update the one row.

Comment: This is my code in each web page... should i just change the insert and say update for the last two pages? string sql = "INSERT INTO tblMyName " +
                  "(Name)" +
                  "Values " +
                  "(@Name)";
        CMethods.executeNonQuery(sql, "@Name", lblName.Text.Trim(),

Comment: First should be something like `INSERT INTO tblMyName (Name) VALUES (@Name)`. If Name is the Primary Key of the table, the next should be updates, like `UPDATE tblMyName SET Age = @Age WHERE Name = @Name`
Be aware that I assume here that "Name" is the Primary Key (or at least a Unique Key) of the table. I would suggest adding an ID field of type integer (or UUID, or something like that) and using that as the Primary Key. That would make the insert statement more like:
`UPDATE tblMyName SET Age = @Age WHERE ID = @ID`

Comment: what if I am not using an ID or primary keys?

Comment: To be honest, you should. A (SQL) database table without a primary key is very bad database design.